# Dirección Ip de una PC

Tags: java

Cómo se puede obtener la dirección IP de una computadora desde el código de una aplicación en el lenguaje de programación Java

Comment: Agrega tus avances para que entendamos mejor la preguntas y evitarias los negativos

Comment: Bienvenida .Ary Moreno, te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, por lo tanto **te sugiero modificar tu pregunta, agregar lo que has realizado, más información, etc**, saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Prueba usando esta función `InetAddress.getLocalHost()`

Ejemplo:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      InetAddress ip;
      try {

        ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        System.out.println("Tu dirección IP es : " + ip.getHostAddress());

      } catch (UnknownHostException e) {

        e.e.printStackTrace();

      }

    }
```